# How to read/access a private file from a private S3 bucket in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is how you can access a *public* file on S3 in React.js:

```
fetch('https://bucketnmame.s3.amazonaws.com/folder1/folder2/file.txt')
.then ((response) => response.text())
.then (data => {
  console.log(data)
});
```

How would you be able to access a *private* file in a *private* S3 bucket? I would imagine that there would be alot of annoying authentication steps to go through.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access a file from a private S3 bucket, you should create a [presigned URL](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generate-presigned-url-modular-aws-sdk-javascript/) for the file.

Usually, this happens on backend, afterwards the URL is passed to the front-end application. Assuming that the back-end has access to the bucket, no additional authentication is needed.